# Dynamically change WCF endpoint address using a behavior

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I want to dynamically change the address of a WCF service called from my client based on custom information in the client's application configuration file.

My first attempt was to create an endpoint behavior, and implement the `IEndpointBehavior.Validate` method, implemented something like the following:

```
void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
{
    ... endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(...);
}
```

This method is called before the client attempts to connect, and appears to successfully change the endpoint address.  However the WCF infrastructure appears to still attempt the connection using the original address.

Is there any way to achieve this using an endpoint behavior or some other WCF extension point?

Comment: Why not just use the proxy class constructor that takes an `EndPointAddress`?

Comment: I can't achieve what I want using the proxy class constructor (actually in my case a ChannelFactory<T> constructor) because at that point I don't yet know what address to use.

Comment: How can you not know the address in the time of creating proxy?

Comment: My goal is to have endpoint behavior elements in the app config file that define the changed addresses of my services.  And when I construct my ChannelFactory<T> I don't yet have access to the endpoint and its behaviors.

Comment: Joe -- did you ever find the correct implementation to acheive your goal?

Comment: @Jennifer, no I wasn't able to achieve this without modifying the client code.  Once I accepted I had to modify the client code, I could pass the address to the proxy class constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the base functionality of CommunicationObject. When the communcitation object moves to Opened state it cannot change anything. So if your communication object (Channel or ChannelFactory) is already in Opened state you can't change address.

Comment: That sounds plausible.  Presumably IEndpointBehavior.Validate is executed too late, after the ChannelFactory is opened.  I'm wondering are there any other extension points that allow me to attach behavior to the endpoint before the ChannelFactory is opened, so I can achieve my goal.